# How to create Grand total columns that only count some sub-columns in pivot tables?

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I use a fairly filled pivot table for the budget and balance of my ensemble. We categorise each expense quite extensively, and I would like to obtain the 'grand totals' in a column of my budget for the year, per expense category (as in, row), and next to it the matching grand totals column for actual expenses. Please see below a sample of the pivot table.

[image]

What I want for each row, at the right end of the pivot table is a TOTALS column that adds up either:

- Columns D, F, H, J (which are under the 'budget' sub category)
- Columns E, G, I, K (which are under the 'actuals' sub category)

I know that the basic options of the pivot tables have a 'Grand totals' check box, but unfortunately, it adds up the budget and actuals for each row.

EDITED: Additional information of how the data is set up.
All my data is in a separate tab, with the following columns:
[image]
The columns Category, Description, Concert, budget/Actuals each use drop-down lists.
Please note that I use Excel as part of Office Professional 2019.

Any guidance to resolve my challenge would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I mocked up some data and by default Excel gave me the two columns you seem to be wanting.  Can you give us a glimpse at the raw data you're working from and maybe an idea how you've set up your Fields?  Also, what version of Excel you're using.